# tf.keras.Model doesn't find assigned variables

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

Look at this code (assume Tensorflow 2.1 or 2.2):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input([])
var = tf.Variable(3.0)
out = var*inputs

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
print(model.variables)             # prints []

model.saved_vars = tf.Module()
model.saved_vars.var = var

print(model.saved_vars.variables)  # prints (<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>,)
print(model.variables)             # prints []
```

Why is `model.variables` empy? I would expect to contain `var`.
As I understant the `tf.Module`, it works as a namescope and also records `tf.Variable` assigned to their attributes. Since a `tf.keras.Model` is a `tf.Module`, it should do the same recursively, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module#attributes), `variables` are Sequence of variables owned by this module and its submodules. But when we tested in Tensorflow version 2.2.0, the `model.variables` is not displaying variables of submodules.

Variables are automatically tracked when assigned to attributes of types inheriting from `tf.Module`. As you are doing `model.saved_vars = tf.Module()`, the `model.saved_vars` submodule becomes a named container for `tf.Variables`. Since `tf.keras.Model` is by default a `tf.Module`, you can assign var directly. But as you rightly mentioned the `model.variables` must record `tf.Variables` of submodule `model.saved_vars`.

**Code -** Tried adding another submodule inside `model.saved_vars` to check if `print(model.saved_vars.variables)` gives submodule  variables. But still No.

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
var = tf.Variable(3.0)
out = var*inputs_1

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs_1, outputs=out)
print(model.variables)             # prints []

# Create Module
model.saved_vars = tf.Module()
model.saved_vars.var = var

model.var = var

print(model.saved_vars.variables)
print(model.variables)  

# Create Sub Module
model.saved_vars.saved_vars2 = tf.Module()
model.saved_vars.saved_vars2.var2 = var

print(model.saved_vars.variables)
print(model.variables)
```

**Output -**

```
[]
(<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>,)
[<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>]
(<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>,)
[<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>]
```

Will share more information as and when we get.

Comment: @RobertC - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, it doesn't explain much. I was just asking why there are no variables (or trainable_variables) in that model. The code you posted, just pushes the question back to weights, which is another property.

Comment: `trainable_variables`  and `trainable_weights` are one and same . They are  variables(weights) and biases of the model. These are the list of variables to be included in backprop. `variables` is just the variables(weights) of the model. As explained above there is nothing for your model to be trained thus its a empty list. Coming to `weights` property, it is both `trainable_weights` + `non_trainable_weights` and this is not Variable(weights) I am referring to .

Comment: Hope the above comment answers your queries. Kindly let us know if you need more clarifications. Will be happy to help.

Comment: I know what those attributes should represent. What I'm asking is: given how `tf.Module` works, why are they empty for the `keras.Model` above? The question is not about training. I can train just fine, computing the gradient on `model.saved_vars.trainable_variables`

Comment: I get what you are saying. Modified the answer, but somehow the submodules variables are not captured in parent module. Tried adding another submodule under model.saved_vars to see if it captured in its parent module, but no luck. Will share more information on availability. Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: After all, it can be a bug. There are bugs, at least in these firsts Tf2.x versions.